# __free_hook doesn't hook as expected

Tags: c, malloc

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292109/outputting-to-stderr-whenever-malloc-free-is-called) stackoverflow question's selected answer. I decided to log the calls to free too. I made a logging `free`. But the calls to `free` doesn't seem to be outputted correctly.

```
#include <malloc.h>

static void *(*old_malloc_hook)(size_t, const void *);

static void *new_malloc_hook(size_t size, const void *caller) {
    void *mem;

    __malloc_hook = old_malloc_hook;
    mem = malloc(size);
    fprintf(stderr, "%p: malloc(%zu) = %p\n", caller, size, mem);
    __malloc_hook = new_malloc_hook;

    return mem;
}

static void init_malloc_hooks(void) {
    old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;
    __malloc_hook = new_malloc_hook;
}

void (*volatile __malloc_initialize_hook)(void) = init_malloc_hooks;


static void (*old_free_hook)(void*, const void *);

static void new_free_hook(void* p, const void *caller) {
    __free_hook = old_free_hook;
    free(p);
    fprintf(stderr, "%p: free(%p)\n", caller, p);
    __free_hook = new_free_hook;
}

static void init_free_hooks(void) {
    old_free_hook = __free_hook;
    __free_hook = new_free_hook;
}

void (*volatile __free_initialize_hook)(void) = init_free_hooks;
```

Comment: How do you use your code? You need to `LD_PRELOAD` a shared object (`.so`) file of your code for programs to use these instead of the usual functions

Comment: @Eregrith There is only one compilation unit. So I added this code right after `#include <stdio.h>`. The calls to `malloc` or `new` are correctly logged.

Comment: Try removing your `init_free_hooks` and init both in your `init_malloc_hooks`

Comment: Ok I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_free_initialize_hook
```

Is never called. You need to remove

```
static void init_free_hooks(void) {
  old_free_hook = __free_hook;
  __free_hook = new_free_hook;
}

void (*volatile __free_initialize_hook)(void) = init_free_hooks;
```

And init both hooks in your init_malloc_hooks:

```
static void init_malloc_hooks(void) {
  old_malloc_hook = __malloc_hook;
  __malloc_hook = new_malloc_hook;
  old_free_hook = __free_hook;
  __free_hook = new_free_hook;
}
```